# HTML Agility Pack get classes

Tags: html, web-crawler, screen-scraping, pack

I am having trouble getting an element's class. I am not trying to get an element by class but rather I am trying to get the element's css class.

Here is an example code :

```
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'screen')]"))
        {
            foreach (var i in item.ChildNodes)
            {
                result_class = i.GetClasses().ToString();

            }
        }
```

And the html is in this way :

I am expecting the result_class variable to be equal to "low", in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is an attribute.

```
string result_class = i.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty);
```